# Why is the hydbridization of the N atom (rightmost) in diazomethane sp and not sp2?

Tags: organic-chemistry, inorganic-chemistry, molecular-structure, hybridization

**Why is the hydbridization of the $N$ atom (rightmost) in diazomethane $sp$ and not $sp^2$ ?**

Most books claim that the negative charge (electron pair) of nitrogen can participate in resonance and is placed in a pure $p$ orbital. However, according to the general rule the hydribization number (number of sigma bonds + number of lone pairs) of the $N$ comes out to be $3$ implying ($sp^2$). However, according to several books the hybrdization is $sp$ and not $sp^2$. Why is it so?

[image]

Comment: As always in these questions, draw the resonance structure.

Comment: @Zhe I don't agree with you. We can draw a resonance structure only if we know beforehand that the electron pair is in pure p orbital. But, unless we know that the hybridization is $sp$ we cannot do so. If both the electron pairs were in hybrid sp2 orbitals then no resonance would have taken place.

Comment: You don't have to agree with me, but it does. That's why diazomethane behaves like a carbene and is nucleophilic at the carbon.

In addition, the logic here is backwards. You should be thinking about resonance and whether the electron should go into a $p$ orbital to begin with, not the other way around.